# How to save polygon data on Elasticsearch through Django GeoShapeField inside NestedField?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, geospatial, polygon

The models looks like -

```py
    class Restaurant(models.Model):
        zones = JSONField(default=dict)
```

The document looks like-

```py
    @registry.register_document
    class RestaurantDocument(Document):
        zone = fields.NestedField(properties={"slug": fields.KeywordField(), "polygon_zone": fields.GeoShapeField()})

    class Index:
        name = 'restaurant_data'

        settings = {
            'number_of_shards': 1,
            'number_of_replicas': 0
        }

    class Django:
        model = Restaurant

    def prepare_zone(self, instance):
        return instance.zone
```

After indexing the mapping looks like-

```json
    "zone": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "polygon_zone": {
                 "type": "geo_shape"
              },
              "slug": {
                 "type": "keyword"
              }
             }
            }
```

But when I am saving data on **zones** field by following structure-

```json
[{"slug":"dhaka","ploygon_zone":{"type":"polygon","coordinates":[[[89.84207153320312,24.02827811169503],[89.78233337402344,23.93040645231774],[89.82833862304688,23.78722976367578],[90.02197265625,23.801051951752406],[90.11329650878905,23.872024546162947],[90.11672973632812,24.00883517846163],[89.84207153320312,24.02827811169503]]]}}]
```

Then the elasticsearch mapping has been changed automatically by the following way-

```json
"zone": {
  "type": "nested",
  "properties": {
    "ploygon_zone": {
      "properties": {
        "coordinates": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "polygon_zone": {
      "type": "geo_shape"
    },
    "slug": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

That's why when I try to search on **zone__polygon_zone** field, it always returns empty because its not polygon type data.

So, how can I save polygon data on elasticsearch trough django by nested geoshape field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a type while index the data. Instead of `ploygon_zone`, it should be `polygon_zone`. I believe fixing the typo will solve the issue that you are facing.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't notice this. It's now working.